# Angular2 JSON service not working properly

Tags: json, angular

I'm following the Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial and am trying to implement something similar but am having issues. I think I may be missing something, but I'm not getting an error message and am not sure how to debug.

The code compiles with no issues. When I run the app in my browser it shows nothing where it should show the members data. In the console I see no errors.

memberlist.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Member } from './member';
import { MembersService } from './members.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'member-list',
    template: `             
                <ul *ngFor="let member of members; let i = index;">
                    <li>
                        <strong>{{member.name}}</strong>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                {{members}}
              `
})

export class MemberListComponent {
    members: Member[];

    constructor(private memberService: MembersService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getMembers();
    }

    getMembers(): void {
        this.memberService
            .getMembers()
            .then(members => this.members = members);
    }
}
```

members.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Member } from './member';

@Injectable()
export class MembersService {

    private url = 'http://localhost:8080/members';  // URL to web api

    constructor(private http: Http){}

    getMembers(): Promise<Member[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(response => response.json().data as Member[])
                    .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.log('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

member.ts

```
export class Member {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public name: string,
        public color: string
    ){}
}
```

JSON string when I enter localhost:8080/members in my browser:

> [{"id":0,"name":"Bob","color":"Blue"},{"id":0,"name":"Bob","color":"Blue"},{"id":0,"name":"Bob","color":"Blue"},{"id":0,"name":"Bob","color":"Red"}]

Comment: Do you see the endpoint being called in the network tab? Can you debug the value of `response` in your service? You are getting `response.json().data` but your JSON string has no property `data`.

Comment: Well now I feel silly, taking off the .data seemed to clear everything up. Thank you for catching that!

Comment: Cool. Cool cool cool.